# Nilpotency of conformal transformation matrices

Tags: quantum-field-theory, conformal-field-theory, representation-theory, lie-algebra

I have recently found the statement that the generators of (infinitesimal) conformal transformations over the algebra of fields at the origin must be nilpotent. This claim is said to follow from the basic conformal algebra commutation relations:
\begin{equation}
[K^\mu,K^\nu]=0,\\
[K^\mu,D]=-K^\mu,\\
[K^\mu,M^{\alpha\beta}]=g^{\alpha\mu}K^\beta-g^{\beta\mu}K^\alpha,
\end{equation}
where $K^\mu$ are the generators of conformal transformations, $D$ is the generator of dilatation and $M^{\mu\nu}$ are the generators of Lorentz transformations.

What I should prove is that $(K^\mu)^n=0$ for some $n\in\mathbb N$. My argument goes as follows.
Suppose there are $N$ fields, so that the generators will be represented by $N\times N$ matrices. If $(K^\mu)^n\ne 0\;\forall n\in\mathbb N$, then, at some point, we would find a matrix that can be written as a linear combination of the previous ones (which can be assumed to be linearly independent)
\begin{equation}
(K^\mu)^N=\sum_i c_i (K^\mu)^{n_i}, \quad n_i<N.
\end{equation}
From the commutation relation with $D$, it would follow
\begin{equation}
-N\sum_i c_i (K^\mu)^{n_i}=-N(K^\mu)^N=[(K^\mu)^N,D]=\sum_i c_i [(K^\mu)^{n_i},D]=-\sum_i c_i n_i (K^\mu)^{n_i}.
\end{equation}
Then, by the linear independecy, we would have $c_i n_i=c_i N$, which implies $c_i=0$ and $(K^\mu)^N=0$.
Is this proof valid?

**Other elements (such as $D$ and $M^{\alpha\beta}$) could be included in the expansion of $(K^\mu)^N$, but since they commute with $D$, they don't affect the reasoning.**

Comment: Your assumption is that $N$ is finite, but that is not true in general. From what I remember, we note that $K$ lowers the scaling dimension $\Delta$ of a state by one and since $D$ is the Hamiltonian of the system which we assume to be bounded below, $K^m = 0$ for some $m$ (because otherwise there would exist states with energy lower than the minimum).

Comment: How is D the Hamiltonian?

Comment: A CFT is studied on a cylinder $S^{d-1} \times {\mathbb R}$ where the Hamiltonian is related to the usual time translations along $\tau$. We then conformally map the cylinder to the plane. Under this map, time translations becomes scale transformations and the operator that generates this is $D$. In other words, $D$ is the Hamiltonian in radial quantization.